# Using Socket.io with React using properties how to properly manage lifespan

Tags: reactjs, socket.io

I am using `socket.io`, I have a component that uses a property as an ID key like `this.props.dataKey` to determine what web socket path to subscribe to.

```
var path = "/data/" + this.props.dataKey + "/subdata"
socket.on(path, handleData.bind(this));
```

One thing I noticed is that the `handleData` function will get called when the component is unmounted, so I added a unsubscribe call on `componentWillUnmount`

However IF the data key property changes I wanted to handle that as well and unsubscribe to the old path and subscribe to the new path.

I started by using `componentWillUpdate` and `componentWillMount` to track subscribe/unsusbcribe but I noticed that those functions are marked deprecated these days in 16.3

So I started using getDerivedStateFromProps to write to the state if the property `state = {path,lastpath, subscribed}`  and then if !subscribed in the render method unsubscribe to the last path and subscribe to the new path

```
if(!this.state.subscribed)
{
    if(this.state.lastpath){socket.removeListener(this.state.lastpath);}
     socket.on(this.state.path, handleData.bind(this));
    this.setState({subscribed:true});
}
```

unfortunately I get a warning saying setting state in render is an anit-pattern and that I should instead use componentWillMount. But componentWillMount is only fired on creation not on update so that means changed props effect wont get effected. Additionally both componentWillMoutn and componentWillUpdate are deprecated. So what is the proper place to handle this? It cannot be handled in getDerrivedStateFromProps has that's a static function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well I think you are on the right track

```
class Component extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    dataKey: PropTypes.string.isRequired
  }

 state = {
   dataKey: false
 }

 getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
   return {
     dataKey: nextProps.dataKey
   }
 }

componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
 if (this.state.dataKey !== prevState.dataKey) {
     this.subscribe(this.state.dataKey)
   }

   if(prevState.dataKey && this.state.dataKey &&
     prevState.dataKey !== this.state.dataKey) {
      this.unsubscribe(prevState.dataKey)
   }
}

 componentWillUnmount() {
   this.unsubscribe(this.state.dataKey)
 }

 subscribe(key) {
   const path = `/data/${key}/subdata`
   socket.on(path, this.handleData.bind(this));
 }

 handleData(data) {
  console.log(data)
 }

 unsubscribe(key) {
  socket.unsubscribe(key)
 }

}
```

Map from Dan Abramov could help

[image]

Comment: Wow really nice complete example, but getDerivedStateFromProps is static so it cannot access this

Comment: @Jim well yeah, sorry for that, you need to hook to `componentDidUpdate` which is called for new state I just moved logic there and instead of `prevProps` you have `prevState` and current state is inside `this.state` (which was previously called from derived state) does it makes sense? `componentDidUpdate` is not deprecated (I updated answer)

Comment: yeah looks like componentDidMount/compoentDidUpdate is the right place to do it, definitely makes sense with the new data flow. Thanks for the help!